# How is the colloquial "One moment X, and the next Y" commonly expressed in German?

Tags: expression, colloquial

In conversation, I just said:

> Die reinste Folter. **Da** wähnt man sich als glorreicher Sieger **und** erliegt **dann**  einer unerwarteten Verletzung...

We were talking about how arduous it must be for top athletes to survive in the competitive world. Essentially, I wanted to express the idea of:

- **One moment** you're X, **and the next** Y.

... referring to a drastic shift from X to Y.

I'm wondering if my phrasing starting with "da", though not a literal rendering, 
gets across the meaning well enough? How is this idea commonly/idiomatically expressed colloquially in German?

Comment: Incidentally, does "sich wähnen" sound a bit too formal to be used in casual conversation?

Comment: It's more a problem of sociolect than casual vs. formal.

Comment: There are plenty different ways to express that idea. Your sentence gets the meaning accross quite well thought I would use a stronger contrast in the 2nd half like `... und (dann) plötzlich ...` but that's just my way of speaking.

Comment: "mal biste der Hund, mal biste der Schwanz" is a phrase for me to express sudden changes of "i rule" to "i got ruled". I just don't find a homepage referring it, too.

Comment: Also on an unrelated note, I can only guess what you intend to say, but just to be clear, _einer Verletzung erliegen_ means to die as a result of an injury _(succumb to an injury)_. Based on the context, I personally would have expected something like _... und erleidet dann eine unerwartete Verletzung/... und zieht sich dann eine unerwartete Verletzung zu_.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a turn from a positive to a negative (or less positive) state, the most common way would be

> **Gerade noch** wähnt man sich als Sieger, **und dann** passiert...

Instead of *gerade noch* you could say *eben noch*, it wouldn't make any difference.
However, your version starting with **da** would be understood.

I would *not* consider "sich wähnen" as too formal for a casual conversation.

In some contexts you can even leave out the verbs and use incomplete sentences:

> **Gestern noch** der strahlende Held, **heute** der Buhmann der Nation

*Yesterday the shining hero, today the scapegoat of the nation*